# Unable to instantiate fragment make sure class name exists

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

> android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate
>   fragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has a empty
>   constructor that is public.

I realize there are many questions posted regarding the same error, but none have helped me so far. I am learning from a book, and have actually run the exact(99% sure) code before. After erasing it all and rewriting it for review, the error came up.

```
package com.paad.todolist;

import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ToDoListFragment extends ListFragment{

    public static ToDoListFragment newInstance(int index) {
        ToDoListFragment f = new ToDoListFragment();

           Bundle args = new Bundle();
           args.putInt("index", index);
           f.setArguments(args);

           return f;
        }
    }
```

LogCat:

> 06-16 03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 06-16
>   03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.paad.todolist/com.paad.todolist.ToDoListActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error
>   inflating class fragment 06-16 03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
>   06-16 03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
>   06-16 03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123) 06-16
>   03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
>   06-16 03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 06-16
>   03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 06-16 03:04:14.091:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(836):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 06-16
>   03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-16
>   03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 06-16 03:04:14.091:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(836):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   06-16 03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 06-16
>   03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 06-16 03:04:14.091:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(836): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
>   Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment 06-16
>   03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
>   06-16 03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739) 06-16
>   03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 06-16
>   03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 06-16
>   03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 06-16
>   03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
>   06-16 03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):    at
>   android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835) 06-16
>   03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at
>   com.paad.todolist.ToDoListActivity.onCreate(ToDoListActivity.java:18)
>   06-16 03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):    at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4466) 06-16
>   03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
>   06-16 03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
>   06-16 03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):    ... 11 more 06-16
>   03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836): Caused by:
>   android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate
>   fragment com.paad.todoList.ToDoListFragment: make sure class name
>   exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public 06-16
>   03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at
>   android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:585) 06-16
>   03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at
>   android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:549) 06-16
>   03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at
>   android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4235) 06-16
>   03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:673)
>   06-16 03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):    ... 21 more 06-16
>   03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836): Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.paad.todoList.ToDoListFragment
>   06-16 03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):    at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
>   06-16 03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501) 06-16
>   03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461) 06-16
>   03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at
>   android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:571) 06-16
>   03:04:14.091: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  ... 24 more

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found that, you logcat says everything

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.paad.todoList.ToDoListFragment
```

Your package name is not correct. use **`com.paad.todolist`** instead of **`com.paad.todoList`**

This post reminds me the TV Show dialog, *Sherlock : You see but you do not observe*  **:) :)**

Comment: Ah, yes! That little error caused me so much pain! I was sitting there looking at your answer like, "um, those are exactly the same..." for a while. Next time Ill pay more attention to the LogCat. Thanks for the help, and nice quote.

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR:**

If you recently migrated files or did any form of copy and paste, check that all your files have an updated package name.

**Full story:**

I created a new module and then copied and pasted the entire *java* and *res* directories from another module after which I deleted the old module. To avoid any possible conflicts, I checked all the Kotlin/Java files and renamed the package name to reflect the name of the new package that the files now belonged to. Here's what I mean:

From:

> com.myapp.oldmodule.presentation.thisfile

To:

> com.myapp.newmodule.presentation.thisfile

Normally, this should have resolved any potential issue. **My mistake however was that I forgot to update the navigation-graph file as well**; It still had references that contained the old/deleted module.

Answer (score 2):

For me this error occurs after moving the `XxxFragment.kt` file using the refactoring feature of AndroidStudio.

It is important to check every place where the Fragment is referenced to find the cause. Some locations are not covered by refactoring. You can find all places while using the global search (Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> twice) for `XxxFragment`.

In my case two places where not refactored automatically:

- `android:name` of the fragment in the `nav_graph.xml`
- `tools:context` import in the `fragment_xxx.xml` file itself.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tutorials/projects from Google and others. I think your main problem now is that the caller *cannot create a new instance of your Fragment*.
One good Google webpage is @ [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Code snippet from the webpage:

```
public static class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * Create a new instance of DetailsFragment, initialized to
     * show the text at 'index'.
     */
    public static DetailsFragment newInstance(int index) {
        DetailsFragment f = new DetailsFragment();

        // Supply index input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("index", index);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }
```

Notes:

- Instead of `extends Fragment`, replace with `extends ListFragment` in your case.
- Notice the method `newInstance`(). This replaces the `new` keyword.